# Loading different css per page on nuxt.js/vue.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using a different css per template/page for example

```
pages/login/step1.vue
  import "~/assets/css/step1.css"


pages/login/step2.vue
  import "~/assets/css/step2.css"
```

but whenever I go from step1 to step2, step2 inherits some from step1 which I don't need.

Any help is appreciated ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way to do that is to put the scoped attribute, like that your css is loaded only for the component asked.

```
<style scoped></style>
```

Hope this answer helped you :D

Comment: my css is pretty bulky and I have decided to put it in assets/css.

Comment: @usupyusuke which means you "decided" to apply it to the entire app instead of just the current component. You can't unload a loaded CSS resource. But you can tell Vue: tweak the selectors of this CSS so it only apples to the current component. That's what `scoped` does.

Comment: what if my css is composed of 600 ~ 1000 lines of css ? these css are from a 3rd party program..